# Splitting texture atlas/spritesheet using text file with sprite regions

Tags: spritesheet, texture-atlas

I have a spritesheet that I am going to use for a game, and since the spritesheet is irregular/not a uniform grid I also have a text file that has the data for each sprite: name, topX, topY, width, and height. (I used https://www.leshylabs.com/apps/sstool/ to create the spritesheet data).

My question is how can I split the spritesheet and export it into separate PNG files using the original spritesheet PNG and the text file with sprite data?

Comment: Would it not be simpler or more efficient to program your game to read this sprite atlas as a whole, and sample the regions from it that your sprites need?

Comment: @DMGregory It would be, if I were using a conventional programming language or game engine, however I am not and it is not possible for me to do that. (I am using the block-based coding language Scratch)

Comment: That's a good thing to include in your question then.